# About performances of TIBCO EMS queues and BW listiners

Tags: .net, wcf, tibco, tibco-ems, businessworks

we plan to use TIBCO EMS queues and TIBCO BW listeners on those queues to invoke some .NET WCF services when a new message arrive. The current setup of ENS in our organization is file storage not database storage of queeu content.

does anybody have experience and evidence of the workload such infrastructure could handle? there are some concerns it could take some seconds for BW to invoke our .NET endpoint when a new message is put in the queue while I was assuming this would happen in near-realtime provided that network and servers are not overloaded of copurse. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom says, and you suspect, this should be near real-time (certainly < 1 sec) but would need to be solved for relevant factors such as message size, operating system, infrastructure and network.

However, I think it's worth pointing out that TIBCO has a WCF binding for EMS that allows you to expose WCF endpoints directly on EMS queues. This may remove the need for having a BW 'bridge' client in the middle and would certainly alleviate the need for this conversation in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have described (using BW as a protocol bridge between EMS and SOAP Services), it shouldn't take "seconds". It should be sub-second. Of course the only way to really know is to test it yourself, but unless there is something highly unusual about your situation, then it should be fast.